# Convert MariaDb query into MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, parent-child

I have query in mariaDB, this query is used to (get ancestors of a child (dog) upto Level 5)

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
SELECT *, 0 level, '      ' relation
FROM dogs
WHERE dog_id = 7

UNION ALL

SELECT dogs.*, level + 1, 'father'
FROM dogs
JOIN cte ON cte.father_id = dogs.dog_id
WHERE level < 5

UNION ALL

SELECT dogs.*, level + 1, 'mother'
FROM dogs
JOIN cte ON cte.mother_id = dogs.dog_id
WHERE level < 5
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY level, relation;
```

I want this query in mysql version: 5.6.45

Here is Table Script:

```
CREATE TABLE `dogs` (
  `dog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `father_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mother_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dog_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

```
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('0', null, null, null);
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('1', 'Father', null, null);
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('2', 'Mother', null, null);
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('3', 'Father1', null, null);
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('4', 'Mother2', null, null);
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('5', 'Son', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('6', 'Daughter', '3', '4');
INSERT INTO `dogs` VALUES ('7', 'GrandSon', '5', '6');
```

Comment: This query cannot be converted into single-query form applicable on MySQL 5.6.45. Use stored procedure instead (or upgrade MySQL to 8+ version).

Comment: The query is taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222165/10138734) - does the real author of both questions is you?

Comment: Nope..
If I upgrade to mysql to 8+version, will this query works?

Comment: Follow provided answer link, follow the fiddle provided in it, change server version, execute.

Comment: Okay..Thank you.

Comment: Why would you downgrade your database?  A solution would be to upgrade MySQL to version 8.